# Another D3 add text to Forced Directed Graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

```
 .link {
    stroke: #999;
    stroke-opacity: .2;
  }

.node  {
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
  font: 10px sans-serif; 
}
```

Now you can get the rest from: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/950642

But here is what I want to do: I want to get rid of the github image in the example above, replace it with a black circle (see image), and have the name to the right of the circle and if the circle is dragged it moves along with the circle (to the right).

I cannot figure out how to do this. I can get the names displayed, but I cannot get the circles to display. And it happens that the names are to the right of where the black circles should be, but I just got lucky. (Side question: how would you get them to the left?)

[image: graph with black circles representing node]

Comment: There are dozens of examples of force directed graphs with circles as nodes, why are you working from an example whose sole purpose is to demonstrate the use of images as nodes?  Also, look up one of the radial tree examples to see how they set text to be either to the left or right of a point according to which side of the graph it is on.

Comment: If you want more specific help, start by posting your own best effort at coding the program, instead of the CSS (irrelevant) from someone else's code.

Comment: If I had found a single (working) example, I would not have posted the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append circle to each node.

Try this code:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/3effD/)**

```
  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(json.nodes)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .call(force.drag);

  node.append("circle")
       .attr("r", 6);
```

Comment: perfect. I did not realize that "g" was important.